# how to make my gaming application as payed version from 3rd stage?

Tags: android

I am doing an gaming application, now my query is i need to give first two stages free and from third stage it need to be a payed version, my gaming application is completed but i am not aware of how to do it as a payed version from third stage, As we can see such kind of requirement in many application

Answer (score 0):

You can add In App Purchase in your game.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html

Just lock your third stage and unlock it on purchase.